# How to associate/retrieve custom data for each TreePanel node in Ext.NET

Tags: extjs, ext.net, treepanel

I want to associate custom data for each node in my TreePanel. Then i will use it in client-side.

Server side looks like:

```
        Ext.Net.Node root = new Node {Text = "Dummy Form"};
        root.AttributesObject = new { nodeType = "Form" };

        Ext.Net.Node section01 = new Node { Text = "Section 01" };
        section01.AttributesObject = new { nodeType = "Section" };
```

**How can i access this *AttributesObject* in client-side?**

Client side looks like:

```
    .Listeners(l =>
    {
       l.ItemClick.Handler = "myClickHandler(item,record,node,index,e)";
    }
```

I tried the followings:

- item.nodeType
- record.nodeType
- node.nodeType
- record.data.nodeType

None of above worked for me, each of them returns "undefined".

Comment: try echoing the root element in console. there you can inspect it and derive the correct way. my guess would be node[index].nodeType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*record.**raw**.[attributeFieldName]* can be used for accessing data client-side.

For a click handler defined as below:

```
.Listeners(l =>
    {
       l.ItemClick.Handler = "myClickHandler(item,record,node,index,e)";
    }
```

Set attribute in server-side:

```
section01.AttributesObject = new { nodeType = "Section" };
```

Access custom set attribute in client-side:

```
function myClickHandler(item, record, node, index, e) {

    var nodeType = record.raw.nodeType;
    console.log(nodeType); //prints "Section"

}
```